# Understanding the Magneto-optical trap

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, atomic-physics, cooling, low-temperature-physics

I am reading about this apparatus at Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magneto-optical_trap

And there is the following sentence which I don't understand:

> "As atoms travel away from the field zero at the center of the trap (halfway between the coils), **the spatially-varying Zeeman shift brings an atomic transition into resonance** which gives rise to a scattering force that pushes the atoms back towards the center of the trap."

I am familiar as to how the Zeeman effect affects the energy levels in a particle with and without spin. For a particle without spin we have 2l+1 sub levels for a given l value. When spin is taken into consideration (I don't know whether is the spin of nucleus or of the electrons) we have 2J+1 sub levels for a given J value. But I don't understand the part in bold. What does it mean to bring an atomic transition into resonance? What is the atomic transition? The superposition of the two states where one is the initial state and the other the final? Can the Zeeman effect split superposed states? And if yes, how many splitting (I am sorry for the vocabulary here) occur? I am confused with the above statement.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know whether is the spin of nucleus or of the electrons

Both. The hyperfine levels used in MOTs comes from the combination of nuclear, electron angular momentum and spin.

> What does it mean to bring an atomic transition into resonance?

You bring an atomic transition into resonance via a laser. This laser couples (e.g. two) states and the let electron "jump" from one state to the other

> The superposition of the two states where one is the initial state and the other the final?

This boils down to Rabi Oscillations. Imaging the laser of proper frequency to be "on" for 0 seconds -> nothing happens. If the laser is "on" for a

> What is the atomic transition?
> Look at the energy level of an atom: A transition means, that the electron "jumps" from one state to another. The energy difference determines the wavelength the laser needs to have to address this transition.

> The superposition of the two states where one is the initial state and the other the final?
> The laser couples the initial state and the ground state. If a laser of proper frequency is on for 0s, then the electron stays in the initial state. If the laser is on for a certain amount of time $\tau$, the electron will be in the excited most certainly. At $\tau/2$, the electron will have a probability to be in the initial or final state of 50% each. Look up Rabi oscillations.